# mysql select records where one of them has n item

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all records if 1 of them contains n, so if I have 3 records and ANY of them has a disposition_id = 1 AND they ALL have a sum time_spent of 20 or more and belong to the same patient_id

```
Table: Transactions
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| id | patient_id | disposition_id | time_spent | created_at |
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 10         |             25 |         10 |      NOW() |
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 10         |              1 |          2 |      NOW() |
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 10         |             12 |          9 |      NOW() |
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
| 4  | 12         |              1 |          8 |      NOW() |
+----+------------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Expected results

```
Table: Transactions
+------------+------------+
| patient_id | time_spent |
+------------+------------+
| 10         |         21 |
+------------+------------+
```

patient_id of 12 won't show even though it has a disposition_id of 1, it does not have 20 or more time spent. but patient_id 10 does have both.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT t.patient_id, t.disposition_id AS did, SUM(t.time_spent) AS sum_time
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE
    YEAR(t.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(t.created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    t.patient_id
HAVING sum_time >= 20
```

I've tried using IN (1, t.disposition_id) in the where and having clauses, but returned 0 records. I feel as I'm close, but just can't seem to put it together.

Comment: you could use subquery in your where clause to search every patient that have disposition_id of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by `patient_id` and then assert your two requirements:

```
SELECT
    t.patient_id,
    SUM(t.time_spent) AS sum_time
FROM transactions t
WHERE
    YEAR(t.created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(t.created_at) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY
    t.patient_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.disposition_id = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(t.time_spent) > 20;
```